# How to do integration tests which do not ends with **/**IT

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml

I have test class which ends with IT i.e SampleClassIT.java.
I have added this class in testng.xml file and used maven-failsafe plugin in pom.xml file.

Plugin used :-

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Is there any way ,so that all the classes which are not extended with IT can also run as a part of integration tests because i have more that 100 classes that i need to refactor them.I dont need to extend my classes with **/*IT.java and make them run as integration tests using failsafe plugin.

Comment: Do that once and follow the conventions of Maven. That makes life easier. Why do you need a testng.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify what classes to include by

```
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**some_pattern*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
```

make your class at-least to satisfy one pattern

Comment: Thanks ... but i have two classes named SimpleTest.java and SimpleDemoIT.java that are added in testng.xml file. I have added the configuration and both tests are running successfully but in log what i can see that results of both the test result are coming separately . I mean it should come

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
but coming
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 after 1st run of test and then
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 after secons test run

Comment: both are in same maven module ?